# facebook Graph API does not return category_list for specific pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am querying a popular [game page](https://www.facebook.com/pg/needforspeed/about)  using facebook graph api to retrieve the category list:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/159460420880667/?fields=category_list,category&access_token=$mytoken

The result shows only the main category without returning category_list field

```
{
   "category": "Games/Toys",
   "id": "159460420880667"
}
```

The same query works perfectly fine for a different page :

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/197958940234297/?fields=category_list,category&access_token=$mytoken

```
{'category': 'Sports Club',
 'category_list': [{'id': '189018581118681', 'name': 'Sports Club'},
  {'id': '184405378265823', 'name': 'Gym/Physical Fitness Center'}],
 'id': '197958940234297'}
```

My question is why the full list of categories was not returned in the first query, and why I am getting the second (not the first) category as a main category?

Comment: I believe Facebook returns the field only when it exists. That would have been best to return the field with an empty value but that's not how it works I guess.